# How to synchronize data in a Notification Handler: Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following Notification handler in a Swift 4 application configured to run on the queue: OperationQueue.main

```
    // Execute change listener on the main queue
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .modelChange, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: modelChangeHandler)
```

and

```
@objc
func modelChangeHandler(notification: Notification) {

    print("Model Changed !!")

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    {
        if let mediaItems = userInfo["media_items"] as? [MediaItem] {
                self.mediaItems = mediaItems
        }

        if self.loadingAlert != nil && mediaItems.count > 0 && mediaItems[0].url != nil {

            loadingAlert!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            loadingAlert = nil

            curMediaItemIdx = 0
            playMediaItem()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Notification is executed potentially twice at the "same time" (since the notifying service uses multiple threads to update the model) leading to the block

```
       if self.loadingAlert != nil && mediaItems.count > 0 && mediaItems[0].url != nil {
```

being executed twice instead of only once because the condition is met twice.  How can I synchronize this notification handler so it is only run once at a time even when notifications are generated quickly?  Since this handler affects the UI, I'm not sure if its possible to use another type of queue to handle notifications...?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like notification is posted in background queue which means the handler is also called on background queue. Try to call handler's body inside `DispatchQueue.main.async { <your handler> }`.

AND

I'd not recommend you to use NotificationCenter for such cases because:

1. you can block the UI with loading alert forever
2. it's not the best approach

The common practice is to use closures:

```
self.loadingAlert?.show()
self.mediaItemsService.fetchMediaItems { [weak self] mediaItems in
    self?.loadingAlert?.dismiss()
    self?.mediaItems = mediaItems
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add the observer like so:

```
// Execute change listener on the main queue
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .modelChange, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main, using: modelChangeHandler)
```

which I think has the same affect as calling DispatchQueue.main.async inside the handler, no? Also, the service posts notifications from potentially multiple threads, so using closures instead of notifications doesn't automatically solve my problem I don't think.